# Groovy: More elegant way to achieve this?

Tags: groovy

I have following groovy function:

```
def getDependantLibs(updatedLib) {
    def dependants = []
    getAllLibs().each { lib ->
        try {
            def ref = getFromStash("/repos/${lib}/dependencies.json").find { it.name == updatedLib }
            if (ref != null) {
                dependants.add([ name: lib, version: ref.version ])
            }
        } catch (err) {}
    }
    return dependants
}
```

My question is, can I achieve this in a more elegant way (maybe with groovy Collecion functions like collect, flatten, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `collectMany`.  E.g.:

```
def deps = [1,2,3,4]
println deps.collectMany{
    try {
        if (it&1) {
            throw new RuntimeException(it.toString())
        }
        (0..it).collect{
            [x: it]
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        println "failed: $e.message"
        return []
    }
}
// output:
// failed: 1
// failed: 3
// [[x:0], [x:1], [x:2], [x:0], [x:1], [x:2], [x:3], [x:4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [`Collection.each(Closure closure)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#each(groovy.lang.Closure)) you can utilize [`Collection.collect(Closure transform)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collect(groovy.lang.Closure)) for transforming each element of the list from one format to another and [`Collection.findAll(Closure predicate)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)) to filter `null` elements from final list. Something like this:

```
def getDependantLibs(updatedLib) {
    return getAllLibs().collect { lib ->
        try {
            [lib: lib, ref: getFromStash("/repos/${lib}/dependencies.json").find { it.name == updatedLib }]
        } catch (err) {
            [lib: lib, ref: null]
        }
    }.findAll { it.ref != null }.collect { [name: it.lib, version: it.ref.version] }
}
```

#### Using Java 8 Stream API

You can always use Java 8 Stream API with Groovy. The main advantage of using Stream API in this case is that all operations on stream are lazy - they are executed when [reduction function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html) is called. It means that you can apply n-number of transformations and only one iteration will be triggered. In Groovy if you apply let's say 3 bulk collection methods, Groovy will iterate 3 times.

Below you can find an example of using Java 8 Stream API in Groovy:

```
def getDependantLibsWithStream(updatedLib) {
    return getAllLibs().stream()
            .map({ lib ->
                try {
                    [lib: lib, ref: getFromStash("/repos/${lib}/dependencies.json").find { it.name == updatedLib }]
                } catch (err) {
                    [lib: lib, ref: null]
                }
            })
            .filter({ it.ref != null })
            .map({ [name: it.lib, version: it.ref.version] })
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

I hope it helps.